# Gradient of element-wise logarithm: $f(x) = \sum\log(\mathbf{A}^{T}(g(x) - b))$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Lets say I have the following equation

$$
f(x) = \sum\log(\mathbf{A}^{T}(g(x) - b))
$$
Where $g:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N\quad$ $x,b\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, and the logarithm is the **element-wise** logarithm.  That is, each element of the sum that gives $f(x)$ is equal to the to the scalar product between rows of $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ and the vector $g(x) - b$.

The gradient $\nabla_x g(x)$ is known, and I would like to take the gradient $\nabla_x f(x)$.  If I define the $i$-$th$ column of the matrix $A$ as $A^{(i)}$, and the $(i,j)$-$th$ element as $A^{(i,j)}$ I believe that this gradient should look something like this
$$
\nabla_x f(x) = \left[\sum_i\frac{A^{(i,1)}\partial_{x_1}g(x)}{A^{(i)T}\cdot(g(x) - b)} ,\cdots, \sum_i\frac{A^{(i,n)}\partial_{x_n}g(x)}{A^{(i)T}\cdot(g(x) - b)}\right]^{T}
$$
where I've used $\partial_{x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$

Here are my questions

1. Is this correct?
2. How can I write this in some kind of convenient vector notation?  Eventually I need to write this in code - assume I have $\nabla_x g(x)$ as a vector already - and I don't want to have to write it out as an iteration over the elements of the vector.  That would really suck.
3. Lets say I now want to take the gradient $\nabla_b\left(\nabla_x f(x)\right)$, is this just going to be a square matrix, where the elements are a simple application of the quotient rule on each of the terms above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}$For
typing convenience, let $\o$ denote the all-ones vector and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
p &= A^T(g-b)
 \quad&\iff\quad P = \D(p) \\
q &= P^{-1}\o
 \quad&\iff\quad Q = \D(q),\quad PQ = I \\
H &= \nabla_x g
 \quad&\iff\quad dg = H\,dx \\
R &= P^{-1}Q \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
NB: When $(A,B)$ are vectors, the Frobenius product corresponds to the ordinary dot product.

Write the function using the above notation, then calculate its  differential and gradient wrt $x$.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \o:\log(p) \\
df &= \o:P^{-1}dp \\
  &= P^{-1}\o:dp \\
  &= q:A^Tdg \\
  &= Aq:H\,dx \\
  &= H^TAq:dx \\
w\doteq\grad{f}{x} &= H^TAq \qquad \big({\rm new\,gradient}\big) \\
}$$
To calculate the $k^{th}$ component, multiply the gradient by the corresponding basis vector
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{x_j} = \e_j^TH^TAq \\
}$$
Now calculate the gradient of this gradient wrt $b$
$$\eqalign{
 q &= P^{-1}\o \\
dq &= \c{dP^{-1}}\o \\
  &= \c{-P^{-1}dP\,P^{-1}}\o \\
  &= -P^{-1}dP\,q \\
  &= -P^{-1}Q\,dp \\
  &= +R\;(A^Tdb) \\
\\
dw &= H^TA\,dq \\
 &= H^TA \, (RA^Tdb) \\
\grad{w}{b} &= H^TARA^T \;=\; \hess{f}{b}{x} \\
}$$
Reversing the order of differentiation yields
$$\eqalign{
\hess{f}{x}{b} &= \left(\hess{f}{b}{x}\right)^T
 =\; ARA^TH \\
\\
}$$

---

Note that the cyclic property of the trace permits the terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in a number of useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
The matrix on either side of the colon must have exactly the same dimensions, as is the case with a Hadmard product. Speaking of which,
the Frobenius and Hadamard product commute with each other
$$A:B\odot C = A\odot B:C
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} C_{ij}$$

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you.  Two questions; lets say I wanted to generalise the sum to a weighted sum.  In your notation, this corresponds to using a vector $c$ instead of a vectors of ones.  Then we have $PQ = \D(c)$, therefore $dP\,q = Q\D(c)dp$?  Second question - could you please explain what is going on in that second line with the highlighted red?

Comment: Actually I take it back - it seems the weighting of the sum is entirely wrapped up in Q, so it shouldn't affect the second calculation?

Comment: 1) $P,Q,C$ are diagonal matrices such that $PQ=C;\;$ the defining vector can be recovered from any diagonal matrix by multiplying by the all-ones vector, e.g. $\,p=P{\tt1}.\;$ 2) The red highlighted formula is a [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Derivative_of_the_matrix_inverse) formula for the derivative of the matrix inverse. 3) You didn't ask but diagonal matrices commute, so $PQ=QP\;\implies\;Pq=Qp\;$